# Setting Combobox value when switching screens

Tags: javafx, combobox, fxml

I want to switch between FXML-Files with Radiobuttons without losing the Combobox-Selection. "secSelectionModel()" seems to add a Selection, but its not visually shown.

```
public class Controller {
    static SingleSelectionModel cbxSelection;
    @FXML private ComboBox<String> cbx = new ComboBox<>();
    @FXML private RadioButton radio1 = new RadioButton();
    @FXML private RadioButton radio2 = new RadioButton();

    @FXML private void cbxFill(){
        cbx.getItems().setAll("eins","zwei");
    }

    @FXML private void screenSwitch() throws IOException {
        Stage stage;
        Parent root;

        if(radio1.isSelected()){
            stage=(Stage) radio1.getScene().getWindow();
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
            //cbxFill();
            cbx.setSelectionModel(cbxSelection);
        }
        else{
            stage=(Stage) radio2.getScene().getWindow();
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample2.fxml"));
            //cbxFill();
            cbx.setSelectionModel(cbxSelection);
        }
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    @FXML private void getcbxSelection(){
        cbxSelection=cbx.getSelectionModel();
    }
}
```

[If Radio2 is selected, I want to switch to Screen2 without losing the Entered Selection in the Combobox.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qr73O.jpg)

Comment: cbxFill() is added to the Combobox (on shown)

Comment: screenSwitch is added to the Radiobuttons (on Action)

getcbxSelection() is added to the Combobox (on Action)

Comment: I'm not sure what this is supposed to do. Surely all you ever do is set the combo box's selection model to the selection model it already has? That's just a no-op.